# Bash string redirection to stdin: remove newline

Tags: string, bash, redirect, shortcut

Is there a way to remove the automatically added '\n' when using string redirection:

```
$ <<< 'abc' wc -c
4
```

Of course I'm looking for short solutions (things like `<<< 'abc' tr -d '\n' | wc -c` aren't interesting).

Comment: The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) says about that: `The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended`. I guess it's not possible to omit the newline.

Comment: A here string is syntactic sugar for a single-line here document. If you don't want to work with a line (in the [POSIX sense](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206)), don't use here strings.

Comment: Is `echo -n 'abc' | wc -c` short enough to be interesting?